# Right alt not working

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a latin american keyboard and I'm trying to use the right alt key so I can write symbols like the backtip and others.

What I've tried is:

`setxkbmap -option compose:ralt`

I'm under Arch Linux.

Comment: What does `xev` say when you hit right alt?

Answer (score 1):

A command I regurlarly use is `setxkbmap -option l3:ralt_switch us`.

The symbols you want are mapped to the level 3 of your keyboard config, if you look at the definition files in */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/...*.

Cheers